Configure Intel Corporation Device 98c8 to work on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have been trying for the last weeks to get the sound working on my Samsung Book S laptop.
The following is the actual PCI device:
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 98c8 (rev 12)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c18b
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 11
    Memory at 93230000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at 93000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

I have tried reloading ALSA, updating drivers etc. but none of these work. Currently, when I go to settings a generic input/output device is listed but it does not work. Any suggestions? I cannot use sound through the PCI device, Bluetooth doesn't work either.
